# gurobi - Error code = 10004 Unable to retrieve attribute 'X'

Tags: c++, math, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am getting an error in my c++/gurobi file:

Error code = 10004 Unable to retrieve attribute 'X'

I read that this might have something to do with labels? But I don't see how there is a problem.
It works for some input files, but not for others. So I have created a toy file, t5.txt in attachment. This file does not work, but removing the last column and setting 8 to 7 fixes it. I am puzzled...

Below is the output of model.write. Everything seems to make sense, any Ideas what I am doing wrong?
Whenever I do a model.write(test.sol), the program stops, so there seems to be something wrong with the solution>

Attachments: 
main.cpp ->  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/main.cpp

input.txt -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/t5.txt

```
Maximize
  15 student_has_projects4.1
Subject To
 R0: student_has_projects0.0 + student_has_projects1.0
   + student_has_projects2.0 + student_has_projects3.0
   + student_has_projects4.0 + student_has_projects5.0
   + student_has_projects6.0 + student_has_projects7.0 <= 4
 R1: student_has_projects1.0 + student_has_projects2.0 >= 1
 R2: student_has_projects2.0 + 2 student_has_projects5.0 <= 2
 R3: student_has_projects2.0 + 2 student_has_projects5.0 >= 1
 R4: student_has_projects0.0 + student_has_projects3.0
   + student_has_projects4.0 + student_has_projects6.0
   + student_has_projects7.0 >= 1
 R5: student_has_projects2.0 + student_has_projects5.0 <= 1
 R6: student_has_projects0.1 + student_has_projects1.1
   + student_has_projects2.1 + student_has_projects3.1
   + student_has_projects4.1 + student_has_projects5.1
   + student_has_projects6.1 + student_has_projects7.1 <= 4
 R7: student_has_projects1.1 + student_has_projects2.1 >= 1
 R8: student_has_projects2.1 + 2 student_has_projects5.1 <= 2
 R9: student_has_projects2.1 + 2 student_has_projects5.1 >= 1
 R10: student_has_projects0.1 + student_has_projects3.1
   + student_has_projects4.1 + student_has_projects6.1
   + student_has_projects7.1 >= 1
 R11: student_has_projects2.1 + student_has_projects5.1 <= 1
 R12: student_has_projects0.2 + student_has_projects1.2
   + student_has_projects2.2 + student_has_projects3.2
   + student_has_projects4.2 + student_has_projects5.2
   + student_has_projects6.2 + student_has_projects7.2 <= 4
 R13: student_has_projects1.2 + student_has_projects2.2 >= 1
 R14: student_has_projects2.2 + 2 student_has_projects5.2 <= 2
 R15: student_has_projects2.2 + 2 student_has_projects5.2 >= 1
 R16: student_has_projects0.2 + student_has_projects3.2
   + student_has_projects4.2 + student_has_projects6.2
   + student_has_projects7.2 >= 1
 R17: student_has_projects2.2 + student_has_projects5.2 <= 1
 R18: student_has_projects0.0 + student_has_projects0.1
   + student_has_projects0.2 = 1
 R19: student_has_projects1.0 + student_has_projects1.1
   + student_has_projects1.2 = 1
 R20: student_has_projects2.0 + student_has_projects2.1
   + student_has_projects2.2 = 1
 R21: student_has_projects3.0 + student_has_projects3.1
   + student_has_projects3.2 = 1
 R22: student_has_projects4.0 + student_has_projects4.1
   + student_has_projects4.2 = 1
 R23: student_has_projects5.0 + student_has_projects5.1
   + student_has_projects5.2 = 1
 R24: student_has_projects6.0 + student_has_projects6.1
   + student_has_projects6.2 = 1
 R25: student_has_projects7.0 + student_has_projects7.1
   + student_has_projects7.2 = 1
Bounds
Binaries
 student_has_projects0.0 student_has_projects0.1 student_has_projects0.2
 student_has_projects1.0 student_has_projects1.1 student_has_projects1.2
 student_has_projects2.0 student_has_projects2.1 student_has_projects2.2
 student_has_projects3.0 student_has_projects3.1 student_has_projects3.2
 student_has_projects4.0 student_has_projects4.1 student_has_projects4.2
 student_has_projects5.0 student_has_projects5.1 student_has_projects5.2
 student_has_projects6.0 student_has_projects6.1 student_has_projects6.2
 student_has_projects7.0 student_has_projects7.1 student_has_projects7.2
End
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that your lp instance is infeasible so the call to .optimize() results in an infeasible status.  From your code

```
model.write("test2.lp");
model.optimize();
model.write("forum2.sol");

if(model.get(GRB_IntAttr_Status) != GRB_OPTIMAL){
    cout << "niet optimaal " << endl;
}
```

You are writing a .sol file before you check for success.  Gurobi gets the 'X' attributes from the variables when it writes a .sol file.  If the optimization fails, the 'X' attributes aren't available and an exception is thrown.  You should make sure that gurobi has a solution before you write a .sol file, or get many attributes, including 'X', 'Pi' and 'ObjVal'.  The OPTIMAL [status codes](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/optimization_status_codes#sec%3aStatusCodes) assures you that that there is an available solution, but codes like SUBOPTIMAL also indicate that there is a solution available and others like TIME_LIMIT, NODE_LIMIT mean there might be a solution available.  You can get the attribute [SolCount](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/solcount) to get a definitive indication that there is a solution available.

Your problem instance is infeasible because constraints (R1, R7, R13 imply you need at least 3 projects for students 1 and 2, but constraints (R19, R20) imply they can have exactly 1 project each.  You can see this by using the IIS solver.  In interactive gurobi you can get get an [Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.5/reference-manual/node422)

```
m = read("test2.lp")
m.optimize()
m.computeIIS()
m.write("test2.ilp")
```

Comment: I was just about the write that I found that they where infeasible. Added some corrections (i.e. dummy instances) to make it feasible. Not a really clear error message though.