# Ploting results from Gurobi python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gurobi

```
import os
import sys
import math
import cvxopt as cvx
import picos as pic
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gurobipy import  *
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import numpy as np
from scipy import *
#import DeferableLoad
OPTmodel = Model('OPTIMIZER')
#general parameters
Tamb =22
N = 1440 # maximum iteration
i = range(1, N)
COP= 3.4 # Coeffient of performance
'''

Prediction need to be added here

'''
# Datacenter room defintion

R = 10 #length of room
B = 7
H = 9 #Height of room
L = 10
dT = 60
A = 2*((L*B)+(B*H)+(H*L))
Thick = 0.33 # thickness of wall
k = 0.7  # thermal conductivity of wall
mAir = 1.2 * (L * B * H)
C = 718
landa = k * A / Thick
a0 = 0.05 / dT
a1 = 1
ki = math.exp(-(landa * 60) / (mAir * C))  # value that constant and its related to property of room
kc = (1 - ki) * a0
ko = (1 - ki) * a1
kp = (1 - ki) * (COP / landa)
Tmin= 18
Tmax= 27
Tamb= 22
PcoolingRated = 100
Pbess_rated = 30.462
Pbess_ratedN = -30.462
Ebess_min = 0
Ebess_max = 300
with open ('Pcooling.csv','r') as f:
    Pcooling = []
    for line in f:
        Pcooling.append(line)
f.close()
with open ('ITpower.csv','r') as f1:
    ITload = []
    for line1 in f1:
        ITload.append(line1)
f1.close()
with open ('DR.csv','r') as f2:
    DR =[]
    for line2 in f2:
        DR.append(line2)
f2.close()
print ITload
print Pcooling
print DR

for i in range(1,200):
    for it in range(1, 1440):
        Tm = np.empty(1440)
        Tm.fill(18)
        TmA = np.empty(1440)
        TmA.fill(27)
    Phvac_flex = {}
    Phvac_up = {}
    Phvac_down_= {}
    Phvac_up_ = {}
    Pbess_out_ = {}
    Pbess_in_ = {}
    Phvac_down = {}
    Pbess_flex_ = {}
    Pbess_flex  = {}
    Phvac_flex_ = {}
    Pbess_in = {}
    Pdc = {}
    Pdc_base = {}
    Pflex_i = {}
    Tdc_i = {}
    Pbess_out ={}
    Ebess_i = {}
    Phvac_flex[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="PHVAC_flex"+str(i))
    Phvac_up[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PHVAC_up" + str(i))
    Phvac_up_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PHVAC_up_" + str(i))
    Phvac_down_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PHVAC_down_" + str(i))
    Pbess_out_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_out_" + str(i))
    Pbess_in_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_in_" + str(i))
    Phvac_down[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PHVAC_down" + str(i))
    Pbess_flex_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_flex_" + str(i))
    Pbess_flex[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(lb=-GRB.INFINITY,ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_flex" + str(i))
    Phvac_flex_[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PHVAC_flex_" + str(i))
    Pbess_in[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_in" + str(i))
    Pdc[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PDC" + str(i))
    Pdc_base[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PDC_base" + str(i))
    Pflex_i[i]= OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="Pflex_i" + str(i))
    Tdc_i[i]= OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = "Tdc_i" + str(i))
    Pbess_out[i] = OPTmodel.addVar(lb=-GRB.INFINITY,ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="PBESS_out" + str(i))
    Ebess_i[i]= OPTmodel.addVar(ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="Ebess_i" + str(i))
    Pflex_i[1] = 0
    Pflex_i[1] = 0
    Tdc_i[0] = 18
    Phvac_flex[1] = 0
    # Phvac_flex_[1] = 0
    Phvac_down[1] = 0
    Phvac_up[1] = 0
    Phvac_down_[1] = 0
    Phvac_up_[1] = 0
    # Phvac_down_pos[1] = 0
    # Phvac_up_pos(1) = 0;

    Pbess_flex[1] = 0
    # Pbess_flex_[1] = 0
    Pbess_out[1] = 0
    Pbess_in[1] = 0
    # Pbess_out_[1] = 0
    Pbess_in_[1] = 0
    # Pbess_out_pos[1] = -250
    # Pbess_in_pos(1) = 250;
    Ebess_i[1] = 150
    OPTmodel.update()
    '''
    if float(DR[i]) > 0:
        Phvac_down_[i] = 0
        Phvac_up_[i] = float(DR[i])
        Pbess_out_[i] = 0
        Pbess_in_[i] = float(DR[i])
        #Pbess_flex_[i] = Pbess_in_[i] + Pbess_out_[i]
        #Phvac_flex_[i] = Phvac_down_[i] + Phvac_up_[i]
        OPTmodel.update()
    elif float(DR[i]) < 0:
        Phvac_down_[i] = float(DR[i])
        Phvac_up_[i] = 0
        #Phvac_flex_[i] = Phvac_down_[i] + Phvac_up_[i]
        Pbess_out_[i] = float(DR[i])
        Pbess_in_[i] = 0
        #Pbess_flex_[i] = Pbess_in_[i] + Pbess_out_[i]
        OPTmodel.update()
    else:
        Phvac_down_[i] = 0
        Phvac_up_[i] = 0
        Phvac_flex_[i] = Phvac_down_[i] + Phvac_up_[i]
        Pbess_out_[i] = 0
        Pbess_in_[i] = 0
        Pbess_flex_[i] = Pbess_in_[i] + Pbess_out_[i]
        OPTmodel.update()
    '''
    #print Phvac_up.values()
    #print Phvac_flex_[i]
    print OPTmodel
    OPTmodel.update()
    ConHVAC1 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_flex[i] == Phvac_up[i] + Phvac_down[i], name='ConHVAC1')
    ConHVAC2 = OPTmodel.addConstr(0 <= Phvac_flex[i] , name='ConHVAC2')
    ConHVAC3 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_flex[i] <= PcoolingRated, name='ConHVAC3')
    PH = pd.read_csv('Pcooling.csv')
    PHVAC = PH.values
    newList2 = map(lambda x: x / 1000, PHVAC)
    p=[]
    p=PcoolingRated-newList2[i]
    #CONHVAC4 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_up[i]==np.minimum((Phvac_up_[i]),(float(newList2[i]))))
    #Phvac_u(1:MaxIter) == min(Phvac_u_(1:MaxIter), (repelem(Phvac_max, MaxIter) - (Pcooling(1:MaxIter)'/1000)))
    ConTemp1 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Tm[it] <= Tdc_i[i] <= TmA[it], name='ConTemp1')
    ConBESS1 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_ratedN <= Pbess_flex[i] <= Pbess_rated, name='ConBESS1')
    ConBESS2 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_flex[i] == Pbess_in[i] + Pbess_out[i], name='ConBESS2')
    ConBESS3 = OPTmodel.addConstr(0 <= Pbess_in[i] <= min(Pbess_rated, Pbess_in_[i]), name='ConBESS3')
    ConBESS4 = OPTmodel.addConstr(np.maximum(Pbess_ratedN,Pbess_out_[i]) <= Pbess_out[i]<=0 , name='ConBESS4') # need to modifty
    ConEBESS1 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Ebess_min <= Ebess_i[i], name='ConEBESS1')
    ConEBESS2 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Ebess_i[i] <= Ebess_max, name='ConEBESS2')
    D = pd.read_csv('DR.csv').values
    DRN = map(lambda x: x / 1000, D)
    PDRN=map(lambda x: x / 4.8, DRN)
    if float((PDRN[i])) > 0:
        CON1 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_flex_[i] == Pbess_in_[i] + Pbess_out_[i],'CON1')
        CON2 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_flex_[i] == Phvac_up_[i] + Phvac_down_[i],'CON2')
        CON3=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_down_[i] == 0, name='CON3')
        CON4=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_up_[i] == float((PDRN[i])),name='CON4')
        CON5=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_out_[i] == 0,name='CON5')
        CON6=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_in_[i] == float((PDRN[i])),name='CON6')
    elif float(np.transpose(PDRN[i])) < 0:
        CON7=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_down_[i] == float(np.transpose(PDRN[i])),name='CON7')
        CON8=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_up_[i] == 0,name='CON8')
        # Phvac_flex_[i] = Phvac_down_[i] + Phvac_up_[i]
        CON9=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_out_[i] == float((PDRN[i])),name='CON9')
        CON10=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_in_[i] == 0,name='CON10')
    else:
        CON11=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_down_[i] == 0,name='CON11')
        CON12=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_up_[i] == 0,name='CON12')
        CON13=OPTmodel.addConstr(Phvac_flex_[i] == Phvac_down_[i] + Phvac_up_[i],name='CON13')
        CON14=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_out_[i] == 0)
        CON15=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_in_[i] == 0,name='CON15')
        CON16=OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_flex_[i] == Pbess_in_[i] + Pbess_out_[i],name='CON16')



    OPTmodel.update()
    ConPDC = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pdc[i] == Pflex_i[i] + float(ITload[i]), name='ConPDC')
    # OPTmodel.addConstr(Tdc_i[i]==(ki*Tdc_i[i-1]+(ko*Tamb)))
    #for x in Ebess_i:
        #ConEBESS2 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Ebess_i[i] ==((Pbess_in[i] / 0.75) + (Pbess_out[i] * 0.75)))
    cooling = np.array(pd.read_csv('Pcooling.csv'))
    DRR = pd.read_csv('DR.csv')
    DR = DRR.values
    IT = pd.read_csv('ITpower.csv')
    ITload = IT.values
    newList = map(lambda x: x / 1000, ITload)
    PH = pd.read_csv('Pcooling.csv')
    PHVAC = PH.values
    newList2 = map(lambda x: x / 1000, PHVAC)
    #for y in Tdc_i:
    T=pd.read_csv('TT.csv').values
    OPTmodel.addConstr(Tdc_i[i]==((ki*float(T[i]))+(ko*Tamb)+(kc*float(newList[i]))-((kp*(float(newList2[i])))+(Phvac_flex[i]*3.14))))
    print Tdc_i.values()
    OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_out_[i]<=Phvac_flex[i]  + Pbess_flex[i]<=Pbess_in_[i])
    # Tdc_i[1:len(i)]==(Ki*Tdc_i[1:1438])+(Kc*array2[1:1438])+(Ko*Tamb))
    ConBESS5 = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pbess_flex[i] == Pbess_in[i] + Pbess_out[i], name='ConBESS5')
    #OPTmodel.addConstr(defIT[i]==DeferableLoad.j2 + DeferableLoad.j3)
    # OPTmodel.addConstr(Pdc_base[i]==predictions[i])
    ConFLEX = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pflex_i[i] == Pbess_flex[i] + Phvac_flex[i], name='ConFLEX')
    PcoolingPredicted = pd.read_csv('PcoolingPredictionResult.csv')
    PcoolingPredictedValue = PcoolingPredicted.values
    ITPredicted = pd.read_csv('ITpredictionResult.csv')
    ITPredictedValue = ITPredicted.values
    ConPDCbase = OPTmodel.addConstr(Pdc_base[i] == np.transpose(ITPredictedValue[i]) + np.transpose(PcoolingPredictedValue[i]))
    OPTmodel.update()
    # OPTmodel.addConstr(Pdc_base[i]==prediction[i])
    OPTmodel.setObjective((np.transpose(Pdc_base[i])-float(DR[i]) - (Pdc[i]) ), GRB.MINIMIZE)
    OPTmodel.update()
    OPTmodel.optimize()
    print Pdc_base[i].X
    #print Ebess_i[i].X
    #print Phvac_flex[i].X
    print Tdc_i[i]
    print Pdc[i]
    print Phvac_flex[i]
    print Pbess_flex[i]
    print Pbess_out[i]
    print Pbess_in[i]
    print Ebess_i[i]
    print Pbess_flex_[i]
    print Phvac_down[i]
    print Phvac_up[i]

'''
    def get_results(self):
        """
        This function gets the results of the current optimization model

        Returns
        -------

        """

        HVACresult = np.zeros(1,N)
        BatteryResult = np.zeros(1,N)
        SOC = np.zeros(1,N)
        #r_Q_dot = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        #r_P = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        #r_P_self = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        #r_P_ex = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        #r_Q_dot_gas = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        #Load = np.zeros((self.gp.N_H, self.N_S))
        try:
            for t in range(1,N):
                HVACresult[t]= Phvac_flex[t].X
                BatteryResult[t]=Pbess_flex[t].X
                SOC[t] = Ebess_i[t].X / Ebess_max
        except:
            pass
        return { 'SOC' : SOC , 'BatteryResult': BatteryResult }

    print OPTmodel.getVars()
    # get results
    Temp = {}
    Battery = {}
    Ebess_result = {}
    ITloadd = {}
    for t in range(1,N):
        Temp[t] = OPTmodel.getVarByName("Tdc_i" )
        Battery[t] = OPTmodel.getVarByName("PBESS_flex" )
        Ebess_result[t] = OPTmodel.getVarByName("Ebess_i" )
        #r_P_e[t] = model.getVarByName("P_export_%s_0" % t).X



    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    # plot elctricity
    ax5 = axes[2]
    ax6 = ax5.twinx()
    ax5.plot( [Temp[t] for t in range(1,N)], 'g-')
    ax6.plot([Ebess_result[t] for t in range(1,N)], 'b-')
    ax5.set_xlabel('Time index')
    ax5.set_ylabel('Power Import [W]', color='g')
    ax6.set_ylabel('Power CHP [W]', color='b')

    ax7 = axes[3]
    ax7.plot([Battery[t] for t in range(1,N)], 'g-')
    ax7.set_ylabel('Power Export [W]', color='g')
    '''


print Pflex_i.values()
    # print OPTmodel.getVars()
print OPTmodel.feasibility()
print OPTmodel.getObjective()
print Pdc_base.values()



'''
b = map(float, Phvac_flex)
plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
'''
#c = map(float, Pbess_flex_)
#plt.plot(c)
#plt.show()


print OPTmodel
print Tdc_i.values()


# get results
print OPTmodel.getVars()
# print OPTmodel.getAttr('EBESS_i')
status = OPTmodel.status
print status
# print  Con10,Con12
print Phvac_flex.values()
print Pbess_flex.values()
print Ebess_i.values()
print OPTmodel.objval
print Tdc_i
print Pbess_in
print Pbess_out.values()
    # print Pbess_flex
    # print Phvac_flex
    # print Ebess_i
print Pflex_i.values()
print Pbess_flex_.values()
#print OPTmodel.getVars()
print OPTmodel.feasibility()
print OPTmodel.getObjective()
print Ebess_i.values()
if OPTmodel.status == GRB.Status.INF_OR_UNBD:
    # Turn presolve off to determine whether model is infeasible
    # or unbounded
    OPTmodel.setParam(GRB.Param.Presolve, 0)
    OPTmodel.optimize()
OPTmodel.write("mymodel.lp")
if OPTmodel.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    print('Optimal objective: %g' % OPTmodel.objVal)
    OPTmodel.write('model.sol')
    exit(0)
elif OPTmodel.status != GRB.Status.INFEASIBLE:
    print('Optimization was stopped with status %d' % OPTmodel.status)
    exit(0)

# Model is infeasible - compute an Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS)

print('')
print('Model is infeasible')
OPTmodel.computeIIS()
OPTmodel.write("model.ilp")
print("IIS written to file 'model.ilp'")
```

> I want to plot the computed values from gurobi but when I want to get the X attribute of gurobi variable it says that **AttributeError: it has no attribute 'X'** and the when I cast the value from float to int it just showed me the empty plot but at the lp file I could see the result of each iteration 
>   I am anxiously waiting for your response 
>   cherrs

Comment: Maybe you want to read [mcve]. In a case like you have here creating such an example may require a little bit of work. You should separate the issue into small parts, see which ones are working and then hardcode some data to reproduce the issue, such that the issue is reproduced within some maximum ~30 lines of code.

Comment: And show the whole stack-trace / error.

Comment: @sascha when i want to plot directly from the computed values without X attribute it says TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number and when I cast it to int it just the empty plot , at the lp file that contrain values of optimizer all variables have value

Comment: That's not a complete stack-trace and now you presented two different errors. Hard to help. I really don't know what you expect here. That code is massive, super ugly and there are tons of unused imports and also two wildcard imports (scary).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gurobi - Error code = 10004 Unable to retrieve attribute 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270102/gurobi-error-code-10004-unable-to-retrieve-attribute-x)