# Gurobi returns AttributeError error when accessing current value of a variable with .X attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror, gurobi

I have the following piece of code in my gurobi optimization where  M is a binary variable. I am accessing the value of the variable with .X attribute but when I run my code it gives me this error:

`AttributeError: b"Index out of range for attribute 'X'"`

if I remove .X attribute, the code runs without any error but it returns true for the if statement for all the elements in M variable even if the value is not "1.0". I guess it checks the existence of a value in the variable M which is True even it is "0.0". In this case, after running the code I try to run the same piece of the code (for loops) in the console and there is no such error!.

```
    for s in range(S)
        for t in range(T):
            for f in range(F):
                if M[(a,t,f)].X == 1:
                    print(M[(a,t,f)].X)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gurobi - Error code = 10004 Unable to retrieve attribute 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270102/gurobi-error-code-10004-unable-to-retrieve-attribute-x)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem was that I tried accessing the value of the variable M before optimizing the model is done..